# Axios - Params - Problem with passing the param values in quotes "paramvalue"

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I'm stuck with an axios get request to my firebase realtime database Rest endpoint.

The fetching with postman works well using three parameters (see below) and following produced final url :

[https://projectname.firebaseio.com/latestMeasurements.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="key000010"&endAt="key000020"](https://projectname.firebaseio.com/latestMeasurements.json?orderBy=%22$key%22&startAt=%22key000010%22&endAt=%22key000020%22)

Subsequently I created following simple axios request. For the "startAt" and "endAt" I receive the error "Constraint key field must be a valid key name" as it seems the constraints are not translated in quotes. For "orderBy" parameter I receive "orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path". As the "$key" does also not have quotes in the end url.

I tried multiple ways of passing the params but not one worked. As said, with postman everything works fine...

Any help is appreciated!

```
       axios({
                method: 'GET',
                url:'https://projectname.firebaseio.com/latestMeasurements.json,
                params: { startAt: "key000010", endAt: "key000020", orderBy : "$key" },
            })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log("SUCCESSFUL FETCH", res.data);
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    console.log("ERROR",e);
               
                });
```

example data under /latestMeasurements:

```
[{
    "key000001": {
        "city": "Stockholm",
        "country": "SE",
        "lastUpdated": 1522854000000,
        "latitued": "N/A",
        "location": "(Folkungagatan tillfälligt avstängd)",
        "longitued": "N/A",
        "measurements": [
            {
                "parameter": "no2",
                "unit": "µg/m³",
                "value": -99
            },
            {
                "parameter": "pm10",
                "unit": "µg/m³",
                "value": -99
            }
        ]
    },
    "key000002": {
        "city": "Ulaanbaatar",
        "country": "MN",
        "lastUpdated": 1552513500000,
        "latitude": 47.91798,
        "location": "1-r khoroolol",
        "longitude": 106.84806,
        "measurements": [
            {
                "parameter": "co",
                "unit": "µg/m³",
                "value": 57
            },
            {
                "parameter": "no2",
                "unit": "µg/m³",
                "value": 30
            },
            {
                "parameter": "pm10",
                "unit": "µg/m³",
                "value": 199
            },
            {
                "parameter": "pm25",
                "unit": "µg/m³",
                "value": 217
            },
            {
                "parameter": "so2",
                "unit": "µg/m³",
                "value": 21
            }
        ]
    }
}
]
```

error fetching frontend (here orderBy is fixed in url and not passed as a param to only produce the error on the other parameters) :

[image]

reproduction of this error in postman (param values not in quotes):

[image]

success in postman (param values in quotes):

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON at `latestMeasurements` that you are querying (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Actually Postman has an amazing feature that allows you to translate your request to code. It can generate the exact same request code for Axios so that you don't have this kind of problems

Comment: I know this tool, but as far as I saw it translates the request to a static url, without the param input...

Comment: Here important to know, that I need the startAt and endAt parameters for pagination, therefore need to be dynamic

Comment: I can query with your conditions and data without an error message: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/65643638.json?orderBy=%22$key%22&startAt=%221%22&endAt=%2210%22&print=pretty What is the problem in these results?

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the problem, as I get the expected results here: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/65643638.json?orderBy=%22$key%22&startAt=%221%22&endAt=%2210%22&print=pretty

I think you're struggling with the fact that Firebase Realtime Database keys are always strings, while you are trying to treat them as a sequential numeric (array) indices. Firebase experts strongly recommend against using array indexes like this, for example in this classic blog post: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

If you must use such indexes, you'll need to ensure that you store them in a format where the lexicographical sort order is the same as the numerical sort order. I typically recommend:

1. Prefixing each numeric key with a short alphanumeric prefix, to prevent Firebase from treating the keys as an array.
2. Pad the number values to a fixed length, so that the lexicographical order and numerical order of the keys become the same.

When combined, your JSON becomes:

```
{ 
  "key001": {
    "city" : "天津市",
    ...
  },
  "key002": {
    "city" : "Stockholm",
    ...
  }
}
```

And then your query becomes:

```
params: { startAt: 'key001', endAt: 'key010', orderBy : "$key" }
```

Comment: i reformatted the data. With postman it works great again, altough I have to add "key"  i.e. startAt : "key000001". Considering the axios request the problem still exists, see the updated question with the screenshot. This time the error is different though. But when I insert the postman url directly without params (params then in quotes) the fetching works great. I reproduced the problem in postman and its simply if I dont put the values in quotes. See screenshot two in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url:
                'https://projectname.firebaseio.com/latestMeasurements.json?orderBy="$key"',
            params: { startAt: '"key000010"', endAt: '"key000020"' },
        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('SUCCESSFUL FETCH', res.data);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log('ERROR', e);
            });
```

I not so elegant solution would be to put the param values in double quotes, but I guess there must be more sophisticated ones.